# Openssl asn1parse using java

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, asn.1

I have to ASN1parse an input base64 encoded string

I can do it using openssl with the command

```
openssl asn1parse -out outfile.der -in infile
```

Is there any Java equivalent for the same? I tried many ASN1 libraries but they either produce different results compared to the openssl command or I am having trouble with their initialization.

Comment: I am too looking for an answer to this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

You could decode the certificate, create an java.security.cert.X509Certificate instance out of it (Use java.security.cert.CertificateFactory) and use getters. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question, but answer might be useful for someone else.

If you want to parse Base64 string to ASN1 structure you can use BoncyCastle dependency and should work same as above openssl command.

Please include Bouncy Castle Provider depnedy can be found on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle

Java code:

```
ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) DERSequence.fromByteArray(Base64.decode(base64String.getBytes()));
int n = seq.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ASN1Encodable obj = seq.getObjectAt(i);
    if (obj instanceof DEROctetString) {
        System.out.println(new String(((DEROctetString) obj).getOctets()));
    } else {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```